# design HIT in amazon mechanical turk

Tags: xml, xhtml, mechanicalturk

I want to design an HIT in Amazon Mechanical Turk using command line tool (CLT). The answer part must be something like the following link:

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crA8Y.png)

workers could select multiple choices in each row. I don't want to use dropdown option since it involve extra clicks for workers. I cannot find the proper command in CLT for this aim. The checkbox style is according to the below code (in .question file):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<QuestionForm xmlns="http://mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com/AWSMechanicalTurkDataSchemas/2005-10-01/QuestionForm.xsd">
  <Question>
    <QuestionIdentifier>1</QuestionIdentifier>
    <QuestionContent>
            <Text>question1</Text>
    </QuestionContent>
    <AnswerSpecification>
      <SelectionAnswer>
        <MinSelectionCount>1</MinSelectionCount>
        <MaxSelectionCount>3</MaxSelectionCount>
        <StyleSuggestion>checkbox</StyleSuggestion>
        <Selections>
          <Selection>
            <SelectionIdentifier>per</SelectionIdentifier>
            <Text>person</Text>
          </Selection>
          <Selection>
            <SelectionIdentifier>loc</SelectionIdentifier>
            <Text>place</Text>
          </Selection>
          <Selection>
            <SelectionIdentifier>org</SelectionIdentifier>
            <Text>oraganisation</Text>
          </Selection>
    <Selection>
            <SelectionIdentifier>no</SelectionIdentifier>
            <Text>non</Text>
          </Selection>
        </Selections>
      </SelectionAnswer>
    </AnswerSpecification>
  </Question>
</QuestionForm>
```

which create an output as following:

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GN962.png)

as it could be seen each choice is in a separated line which I want them to be in one line according to image 1. I wondering if there is any command in CLT to create a question like image 1, and if not, do you know any other software to do this.
thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [QuestionForm](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_QuestionFormDataStructureArticle.html#ApiReference_QuestionFormDataStructureArticle-questionform-structure) construct with Mechanical Turk, it isn't possible to define how they'll be rendered (e.g., in a list or in a row). There also isn't a mechanism to define things like CSS or STYLE attributes that'd let you configure this.

If you want more control over how your HITs are formatted, you've got a couple of options. Probably the best one for your needs is to create an [HTMLQuestion](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_HTMLQuestionArticle.html). This lets you use a much broader set of HTML tags, but also means that you'll do more work to get even simple things formatted the way you want. If you want even more control, you can check out [ExternalQuestion](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_ExternalQuestionArticle.html). This takes as input an HTML page that presumably you host or control. With an ExternalQuestion, Mechanical Turk simply loads the page you specify in an IFRAME for Workers. Unlike HTMLQuestion, you have to host the page yourself, but it also means you have the most control (to use your own widgets, to directly access your own database, etc).